# Entity Framework Core 5.0 - Many to many with additional field in mapping table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I'm using EF Core 5.0 and I'm attempting to create a many-to-many relationship:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserItem> UserItems { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserItem> UserItems { get; set; }
}

public class UserItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the `UserItem` class has an additional property called `Quantity`, I was wondering if this is the correct approach, and how would I map all this in the `DBContext` class?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is correct!
But I would recommend removing the Id property from `UserItem` and configure a composite key using -

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserItem>()
            .HasKey(userItem => new { userItem.UserId, userItem.ItemId });
```

in the DbContext so it is ensured that only one single `UserItem` for the same User/Item combination can exist (as I assume you want to use the Quantity property for representing "multiple" relationships between the same two items).

EF Core correctly sets up the relationships and foreign keys for you but you need to tell him which part of the relationship is the principal part.

If you want `UserItem` to be cascaded when the Item is deleted but restrict the deletion of the User when an `UserItem` is still referencing said User then add -

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserItem>()
            .HasOne(userItem => userItem.User)
            .WithMany(user => user.UserItems)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

If you want `UserItem` to be cascaded when the User is deleted but restrict the deletion of the Item when an `UserItem` is still referencing said Item then add -

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserItem>()
            .HasOne(userItem => userItem.Item)
            .WithMany(item => item .UserItems)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

And if you want to restrict the deletion of User and Item if they are referenced by a `UserItem` add both of them. Notice that you will need at least one of them because otherwise you will get an exception when adding the migration because you have multiple cascade paths for `UserItem`.

Comment: This is everything I need! However one question, Can I not map the new composite key to the ID field in the UserItem class?

Comment: @Azhari I dont think this is possible because the composite key consists of two integers and the Id property is only representing a single integer. 

But if you want to keep the Id property but still ensure a unique UserId/ItemId combination you can use an unique index configured by: modelBuilder.Entity<UserItem>()
   .HasIndex(userItem => new {userItem.UserId, userItem.ItemId }).IsUnique()

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine, maybe you will have add to your dbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
          
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserItem>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.UserItems)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Item)
                    .WithMany(p => p.UserItems)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ItemId)
                    
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }
```

but if you use Net5 you are allowed to add a list of items:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserItem> UserItems { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Items> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserItem> UserItems { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have a question regarding delete behaviour:

- If a UserItem is deleted, nothing else should be deleted.
- If a User is deleted, the associated UserItems should be deleted.
- If a Item is deleted, the associated UserItems should be deleted.

^How would I set this up?

Comment: You can try .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade); instead.

Comment: But  I don' t recommend you to do this. In any case it will not be working properly and can cause accidents. The better way is include all items in delete action manually.  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull) - is the most safe option.